# Commercial 2.4GHz antenna construction differences

Tags: rf, antenna, wifi

I am developing a land to land rover remote control system which will operate on 2.4 GHz. I bought several antennas to mount on the rover to test the range (I currently don't have access to any RF measurement tools). Out of curiosity, I disassembled some of the antennas. Most of them were constructed like the bottom antenna (bundled with SIYI MK32E) or were using PCBs. The top antenna, Taoglas GW.71.5153, is different. It has only very short, dipole like structure, and the rest of the plastic is empty!

Why is the plastic cover so big, if the antenna inside is so small? Is the design correct, or is this manufacture mistake and the antenna is incomplete?

[image: GW.71.5153 and SIYI Antenna]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the plastic cover so big, if the antenna inside is so small ?

Marketing. Hard to explain why a smaller antenna might work just as well.

Also, it seems that the polymer encasing comes in a standard size – deviating from that might cost *more* than using a smaller enclosure, due to *economies of scale*.

Comment: Yes, the upper seems same for both antennas, so it is probably cost saving. It is funny, as it was the most expensive antenna. Cheaper antennas used all space with custom designed covers. Sadly, this one wastes lots of space.